# Could not invoke RNPusherPushNotifications.setAppKey

Tags: android, react-native, pusher

I'm using react native and pusher beams to sent real time notifications but i got error

`Could not invoke RNPusherPushNotifications.setAppKey`

what does it mean?

Comment: Hi @basma were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hi @Rigorousimplementation my problem was that i used two packages for notification so it conflicts with each other